# catching extension exceptions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to catch every exception that would be raised from loading extensions, of which i found these in the docs

ExtensionErrors:

- ExtensionAlreadyLoaded
- ExtensionNotLoaded
- NoEntryPointError
- ExtensionFailed
- ExtensionNotFound

This is the code I've been trying to get something working with, but i is too dumb

```
@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):

    try:
        bot.reload_extension(f'Cogs.{extension}')
        await ctx.send(f'reloaded {extension}')

        # raise commands.ExtensionNotFound(extension) # makes **ExtensionNotFound* prints

    except commands.ExtensionNotLoaded: # this works
        bot.load_extension(f'Cogs.{extension}')
        await ctx.send(f'{extension} was not loaded in the first place but i loaded it up for you')

    except commands.ExtensionNotFound: # doesn't catch actual exception unless it's raised
        await ctx.send('commands.ExtensionNotFound')

    except commands.ExtensionError: # didn't test coz i got hung up on the last exception
        await ctx.send('commands.ExtensionError')

    except commands.ExtensionFailed: # didn't test
        await ctx.send('commands.ExtensionFailed')

    except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded: # didn't test
        await ctx.send('commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded')
```

So what I want is a working example of catching the extension exceptions (that.. unlike my weak arse code, does actually work)

Edit1:
If I call the reload function with a none existing cog `!reload not_a_real_cog` I get the following exception:

```
Ignoring exception in command reload:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Discord bots\Discord bot - Cogs V1\main.py", line 136, in reload
    bot.reload_extension(f'Cogs.{extension}')
  File "C:\Users\Bruh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 759, in reload_extension  
    raise errors.ExtensionNotLoaded(name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotLoaded: Extension 'Cogs.not_a_real_cog' has not been loaded.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bruh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Discord bots\Discord bot - Cogs V1\main.py", line 142, in reload
    bot.load_extension(f'Cogs.{extension}')
  File "C:\Users\Bruh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 676, in load_extension    
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'Cogs.not_a_real_cog' could not be loaded.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bruh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Bruh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bruh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'Cogs.not_a_real_cog' could not be loaded.
```

Testing `ExtensionNotFound` again by the methods provided by @CrazyChucky in the comments.. I think i misunderstood what the exception IS to actually to catch it, though I tried to catch:

- `ExtensionNotLoaded`
- `ExtensionNotFound`
- `CommandInvokeError`

But i catched nothing

Comment: So when you manually raise `ExtensionNotFound`, your `except` clause is entered. In what other way have you tested that error (deleting/renaming the extension file, I imagine)? And what happens?

Comment: I think I possibly misunderstood what the exception I'm actually getting to try to catch it because I tried your methods and it catched the exception currently, the exception I seem to not be able to catch is when i try to reload a none existing cog.

Comment: You're catching it, alright. Look more carefully at your error message. The line `bot.reload_extension(...)` throws `ExtensionNotLoaded`, which causes the code to enter your first `except` clause. Then `bot.load_extension(...)`, *inside* that clause, throws `ExtensionNotFound` because it can't find that extension to load. There's no inner `except` to catch that, so the exception propagates.

Comment: Oh! I see my mistake, I thought as long as the whole thing is in a `try` block it would catch everything, thanks for the help!

Comment: @omar yes, everything **in** a ``try`` block will be caught, but an ``except`` is on the same level as a `try`, below it, so **not inside** of it. That means everything in an `except` will **not** be caught because it's not in a `try`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I see that you were unclear on how [`try`/`except` clauses](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) work; you can only catch an exception in the `try` part, and a `try` will only catch the first exception it encounters, immediately aborting and going to the corresponding `except` (or `else`) clause.

In this case, you'll want to nest one `try`/`except` inside another, keeping in mind that you can generate several of the same errors whether you're `loading` or `reloading`, and you don't want your code to repeat itself.

```
@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    try:

        # This inner try/except only cares about whether the extension
        # can be REloaded, or whether it needs to be loaded from
        # scratch.
        try:
            await ctx.send(f'Attempting to reload {extension} extension...')
            bot.reload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        except commands.ExtensionNotLoaded:
            await ctx.send(f'{extension} is not currently loaded. Attempting '
                            'to load...')
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

        await ctx.send(f'{extension} has been freshly loaded.')

    # These except clauses will be reached if their exception occurs,
    # regardless of whether or not the inner except clause was entered.

    except commands.ExtensionNotFound:
        await ctx.send(f"Error: {extension} couldn't be found to load."))

    except commands.ExtensionFailed:
        await ctx.send(f'Error: {extension} failed to load properly.')

    except commands.ExtensionError:
        await ctx.send(f'Error: unknown error with {extension}')
```

*Note: module names in Python are usually all lowercase by convention, so I renamed `Cogs` to `cogs`.*

You might be tempted by the existence of the bot's [`extensions` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.extensions) to do something along these lines:

```
if extension in bot.extensions:
    bot.reload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
else:
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
```

But this is dangerous in an asynchronous environment like this, because it's a race condition: it's possible that between the time you perform the `in` check and when you actually try to load/reload the extension, some other user or process could potentially have loaded/unloaded the extension.